# Squeak Win 7 Error: No content to install

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

So I decided to take a look at Smalltalk.  Googling led me to Squeak and Squeak By Example.  Squeak By Example tells me to drag the .image file onto the Squeak.exe icon.  I do this and get an error:

"Error: No content to install"

If I load squeak.exe by itself, no error message occurs.  I assume this is because it uses the image file that was included in the download from squeak.org instead of the on I'm trying to use.  I've verified that the .image and .changes files are not read only and are unblocked (you know, that little button that exists on the properties dialog of a file that was downloaded from the internet).

Squeak version: Squeak-4.2-All-in-One
SBE: 1.3

What's next?

Edit:
Proceeding with the book a bit, I got to the part where you save the environment, then try to open your recently saved image.  I got the same error.  So it must be an issue with how I'm opening it, or an permissions thing or something.  I made sure both my user and the system user have full control over the image and changes files.  I also tried forcing squeak.exe to run as administrator.  Still having problems.

Saving the default image while exiting instead of a save-as and simply loading squeak.exe (and the default image) worked without error.  I'll look at it some more later.

Comment: If you are interested in exploring Smalltalk you might also look at the Pharo - fork of Squeak that has received quite a lot of clean-up and improvement. There is also accompanying book Pharo by example with more up to date examples. http://www.pharo-project.org/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that when an ImageFile is specified in Squeak.ini (as is the case in Squeak-4.2-All-in-One) that image file is always used. And if you pass a file as an argument to Squeak.exe (or drag and drop it) that file is passed to the image as a *source file* to be executed instead.

If you want to open an image file by dropping it on the Squeak.exe icon remove the ImageFile directive from Squeak.ini